# How to merge api calls with different arguments into 1 call

Tags: rest

I am trying to query a certain api where I want to get the results for every possible argument. The call for 1 given argument looks like url/?arg=samplearg1. If there are 5 different sampleargs, I want the results of the api calls for all 5 of them returned in 1 single call instead of doing 5 separate calls with different arguments. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You should adapt your api call to accept multiple parameters, this way you can handle the logic in your backend and send a single response

Comment: Is there a way to do this even if I dont control the backend of the api? I am trying to query an external api